# Trouble understanding the position of code

Tags: java

I am doing an exercise from the book Head First Java. The output of this exercise should be:

a-b c-d

I tried getting it right but I struggled so I gave in and looked at the answers which are down here:

```
class Shufflel {
public static void main(String[] args){

   int x = 3;

   while (x > 0) {

   if (x > 2){
   System.out.print("a");
}
   x = x - 1;
   System.out.print("-");

   if (x == 2){
   System.out.print("b c");
}


   if (x==1){
   System.out.print("d");

   x = x - 1;


}

}

}

}
```

I have trouble understanding why

```
x = x - 1;
System.out.print("-");
```

and

```
x = x - 1;
```

are positioned where they are.

I can't come up with a logical reason as to why the lines of code have to specifically go where they have to go and not in another position like for example in the if-statement or just below the `while(x > 0){}`- part.

Also, it didn't even cross my mind for a second to put this: `x = x - 1` line of code at the bottom. I have absolutely no idea why it is there.

Comment: Please post code here. Text in images can't be copied/pasted and external links can die.

Comment: Well maybe then this isn't the right book for you. Guess it depends on the person. I like the programmer's choice series.

Comment: what are the instructions to this task? the code does the job - the output is correct, but what's the text of this excercise?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc I've added the code in text. Thank you

Comment: @maraca I guess I'll check it out thank you.

Comment: @RetteMich The task is to rearrange a few code snippets to make a working Java program that produces the output: a-b c-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have initialized

first step : `x = 3;`

then we enter a loop that will run until "x" become "0" to stop.

now we check `if(x > 2)` which is **true** and we print ("a")

after that, `x = x - 1` , which means **x = 2** and we print ("-")

we test again `if(x == 2)` which is **true** and we print ("b c")

now we test `if(x == 1)` which is **false** so we don't do anything,

we restart the loop again :

`if(x>2)` **false** because x = 2 at this position, 
then `x = x-1` so **x = 1**, and we print ("-"), finally `if(x==1)` is true, so we print("d") and **x = 0** after  x = x -1. and we leave the loop because x is not > 0 anymore.

Comment: You're an angel! Thank you so so much you couldn't have made it any clearer!